# Any website or app, where I can talk with russians?

Tags: обучение

Privet :)
Is there any app or webiste where I can talk with native russian speakers for free?
With talk I mean really talk and not just write.

Comment: Mylanguageexchange.com--You may have several false starts before finding someone for a mutually productive chat via Skype. Try to stick with someone whose English is roughly on your level of Russian. I avoid girls and women in general. There's a tendency to let a little romance percolate but the younger the girls are, the more fickle and more quick to take offense at any imagined slight. More mature persons are preferable, especially those who follow a rigidly structured lesson program. At least that's my preference. The pretty girls make me nervous. I'm more at ease conversing with a man.

Comment: @user3847 I think your comment qualifies to be an answer.

Comment: @user3847: +1 for your candid explanations .

Comment: You can speak with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vk.com for one. It's a Russian Facebook clone which many people use as a Tumblr substitute (yours truly included). If you find someone you want to talk to, just exchange Skypes.

As to how to find talking partners, just browse the 'groups' ("Группы") and either search for English learners (then it'll be mutually beneficial), or for groups centred around your interests.

Also, don't be afraid to talk to girls just because they're girls (as a certain user suggested). That's sexist.

And if, by any chance, you're interested in anime/manga, Doctor Who, cats, or Java/Android programming, you can talk to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Interpals](http://Interpals.net). You can find people who actually learn language by using filter.

Comment: Why minus? I used interpals, it is full of russian speaking people.

Answer (score 1):

http://italki.com - there you can find Russians willing to have a language exchange speaking practice (normally it is 30 min in Russian and 30 min in your language, but not necessary). 
Also you can find a community tutor there (informal teaching) and teachers of Russian.

Good luck with learning Russian!